# What commands I use in SharePoint Designer to write my workflow?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, workflow, designer-workflow

I am new to working with Workflow in Sharepoint designer 2013. I am learning inch by inch and trying to manage a contract library. I want to set a workflow with the following algorithm (things in quote "text" means this is a column title). How can I achieve this?

**Workflow**

```
If "Expiration Date" is less than 1 year but more than 190 days

    AND 

   "Current Status" is not 'Active' 

    *// 'Active' is a drop-down choice in "Current Status" column //*

Then trigger this workflow:

1. send email alert to stakeholder
    [I will add the email content]

ELSE

If "Expiration Date" is less than 190 days away 
AND
  "Current Status" is not 'Active'
      1. Send a reminder email alert
      2. Then wait 15 days to loop this alert if 
            the "Expiration Date" is not more than 190 days
             OR
         "Current Status" is not "Cancelled"

Transition To
  End workflow
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to mention the conditions / actions that will help you to execute this algorithm

- Get the difference between Expiration Date and today by days and set it to variable A via `Find Interval Between Dates Action` below `Utility actions`.
- Check with if condition this variable value. you can add nested if / or add another if condition directly below previous if to can do and/ or
- Also with if condition checks this "Current Status" is not 'Active'
- Then from action menu below `core action` select `Send an email` to execute this send email alert to stakeholder.
- Repeat the previous steps at `Else` branch
- For pause, you cause use `pause until date` below `core action`
- For loop, you can use `loop in time or with condition` from the above ribbon

Comment: I will try this. Really appreciate your time. I will comment back once I try it and let you know the results.

Comment: when I go on to SharePoint Designer 2013 and launch a workflow, on the ribbon Under the "Insert" group, I found the *Find Interval Between Dates" in Action. But once I select it, I can set the first option to Day but I cant set the second to choose "Current Item" so that I can select "expiration date". Am I missing something?

Comment: just click on Fx button  , please don't hesitate to tell me if you need any calarfication

Comment: Oh yeah. got it. moving on... thanks for your patience. Moving to second step.

Comment: On the Core Action step, when I select Email "these users" What I want the system to do is to select the user from the "Stakeholder" column rather than force me to designate a set of users. How would I achieve this?

I am presuming I "Assign Task"? and then define the task as an email?

Comment: Click workflow lookup for a user in select user dialog :)

Comment: When I do a lookup, I can only select a user at a time myself. I am trying to get SharePoint to do the lookup. Is that possible?
So, instead of "Send Email to [These User] - where I click in and then select multiple users,  I want SharePoint to select the user from Current Items - Stakeholder column 
If not, then the workaround I can think of is to set an extra condition for Current Item  - Stakeholder - select a name - then do "Send Email" to that name (select manually at this stage from the lookup) Then repeat the conditional process for as many times as there are stakeholders

Comment: Ok, I have done writing the workflow. First test failed to send the email... or for whatever reason I am not getting the test email to myself.